# I can't block Facebook addresses with /etc/hosts

Tags: website, blocking

I've tried several things. I've tried adding a long list of Facebook related URLs. I've tried deleting my `/etc/hosts` file and starting from scratch. Here's how the hosts file looks now:

```
0.0.0.0 apps.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 connect.facebook.net
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
0.0.0.0 fbcdn.com
0.0.0.0 fbsbx.com
0.0.0.0 fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 graph.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 login.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 s-static.ak.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 static.ak.fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 www.connect.facebook.net
0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.fbcdn.com
0.0.0.0 www.fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 www.graph.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.login.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.s-static.ak.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.static.ak.connect.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.static.ak.fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 0-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 1-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 2-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 3-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 4-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 5-edge-chat.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 6-edge-chat.facebook.com
```

Comment: HOSTS enables connections by associating name with IP address. It does not disable anything. So then you need to disable Facebook in Windows Firewall (enter an exclusion) or in your router

Comment: @John You can add hosts to a host file and blackhole them this way. I would recommend the original poster send all traffic to 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: Stupid question, did you restart networking after ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. I suspect your browser is not using local DNS resolution.

Answer (score 4):

This is not working as websites are served via HTTPs and IPv6 protocol by default now a days, so you need to map [As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0oUH.png) Facebook to IPv6’s localhost notation as well. Then you can check if you are able to access facebook by hitting ping facebook.com in cmd/powershell

Like for example

127.0.0.1 [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)

::1 [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)

Comment: HTTPS is entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com login.facebook.com secure.facebook.com latest.facebook.com inyour.facebook.com beta.facebook.com static.facebook.com touch.facebook.com developers.facebook.com newsroom.fb.com pixel.facebook.com apps.facebook.com graph.facebook.com m.facebook.com upload.facebook.com
```

Courtesy of

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-block-facebook-access-on-linux-desktop

Comment: This answer doesn't block facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Something is screwy. If /etc/hosts is not blocking ... perhaps something has been altered so that this file is no longer being referenced by the networking software in your Windows installation?

It works fine for me here. Facebook is blocked, along with several thousand others.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser might be using DNS over HTTPS - this ignores your hosts file and any local DNS settings.

For Firefox:

[image: Firefox DNS-over-HTTPS Settings]
From: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https

For Chrome:
[image: Chrome browser DOH Settings]

From: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/145372-how-enable-disable-dns-over-https-doh-google-chrome.html

Here is an elegant explanation of how it works: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/05/a-safer-and-more-private-browsing-DoH.html

That said, it's not necessarily more secure - in fact, in my opinion it's less secure because it's less decentralized and more centralized - thus easier to track from fewer DNS providers.

Comment: I have the same problem (facebook not blocked) but other websites than facebook are correctly blocked.